# Flex: RemoteObject, passing named parameters

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flex4

I'm calling ColdFusion cfc method using RemoteObject method of the Flex.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:RemoteObject destination="ColdFusion" source="cfc.categoryGateway" id="categoryGateway">
        <s:method name="getCategoryList" result="returnHandler(event)"
                   fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)">
            <s:arguments>
                <orderby>categoryId</orderby>
                <parentCategory>1</parentCategory>
            </s:arguments>
        </s:method>
    </s:RemoteObject>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Where as my cfc accepts the parameter in following manner:

```
<cffunction name="getCategoryList" access="remote" output="false" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="parentCategory" type="string" required="false" />
    <cfargument name="orderby" type="string" required="false" />
    <!--- code... --->
    <cfreturn qCategoryList />
</cffunction>
```

So you can see that I changed the sequence of the parameter, when I call the cfc method. But it does not worked.

It means that `<s:arguments>` does not pass the **named** parameter.
Is there any solution for that? As you can see that I may have some of the arguments not mandatory so, it must be passed by name.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the flex?  Have you tried dumping out the arguments scope to a file to see what is in there when Flex calls the cfc method?

Comment: Yes, coz when I swap the parameters I get the error in SQL Query like: Unable to invoke CFC - Invalid data categoryId for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER. <br/> `parentCategory` is not actually a string parameter but an integer one which I'm useing in SQL query. <br/> If the parameters are in same order, then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments parameter is an array, so regardless of what you name each element, I think it will still use it in order.
You can try doing something like this instead:

```
<s:RemoteObject destination="ColdFusion" source="cfc.categoryGateway" id="categoryGateway">
        <s:method name="getCategoryList" result="returnHandler(event)"
                  fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)" />
    </s:RemoteObject>
```

then call:

```
categoryGateway.getCategoryList({orderby:'categoryId', parentCategory:'1'});
```